# tensorflow.js copy weights from one model to another

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Hello) Is there a best way to copy trained weights from one model to another in Tensorflow.js? Or how to convert model to string?
I need to copy trained weights of model from one worker and send them to another.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the weights of a particular layer with [`tf.layers.Layer.getWeights`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.layers.Layer.getWeights).  This will return a tensor of the weights for that entire specified layer.  You can set those weights with `setWeights` on another model.

To specify a particular layer, you can use the `getLayer` function.  Here's an example of getting a specific layer's weights and printing them.

```js
 tf.loadLayersModel('https://d1zv2aa70wpiur.cloudfront.net/tfjs_quant_nsfw_mobilenet/model.json')
    .then(myModel => {
      myModel.summary() // Lists layers
      const chosenLayer = myModel.getLayer('Conv_1')
      chosenLayer.getWeights()[0].print()
  })
```